# CSRF token error? on laravel Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete, csrf-protection

[first was ok. second  got error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO18d.jpg)
[image]
I use the ajax function on javascript page in laravel

If I initiate the function once it work well 
But when I start the function 2 or 3 times in short time I got the error

```
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
"file": "D:\\AppServ\\www\\come\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
```

I search the error message . The result is  the csfr issue.

But how can I  fix the error?
I have already have the

```
$.ajax({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
```

The question is not on the first time .   It's on the second or third times.

Code

```
$('.findNews_geography').autocomplete({   
        source: function(request, response) {
            var findtable=$('.findtable_num').val();
            var terms=request.term; 
            console.log("findtable="+findtable+";term="+terms);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },


                url: "findNews_geography",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    findtable : findtable,
                    term : terms,
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log("findNews_geography ajax error＝"+xhr.responseText);
                    console.log("findNews_geography xhr.status="+xhr.status+";thrownError="+thrownError);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("see request="+data);
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.place,
                        }

                    }));
                } //success end
            }); //ajax end
        }, //source end
        minLength: 0, 
}); //autocomplete end




 $(".findNews_geography").focus(function () {
         //if (this.value == "") {
       console.log("findNews_geography get focus");
        if($('.findtable_num').val()){
            $(this).autocomplete("search"); 
        }// }; 
  });
```

Comment: do you have `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
` in your head tag?

Comment: YES~I have <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: In the console do you see that the request sends the given token?

Comment: @ka_lin where to find? I post the chrome console image on 
『first was ok. second got error』

Comment: Now I guess it's about the ajax delay replay for the laravel.
But I don't know why and how to fix it~
it happens irregular....

Comment: what is In Your `.env` file APP_URL

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.findNews_geography').autocomplete({   
        source: function(request, response) {
            var findtable=$('.findtable_num').val();
            var terms=request.term; 
            console.log("findtable="+findtable+";term="+terms);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },


                url: "findNews_geography",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    findtable : findtable,
                    term : terms,
                    _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')  
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log("findNews_geography ajax error＝"+xhr.responseText);
                    console.log("findNews_geography xhr.status="+xhr.status+";thrownError="+thrownError);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("see request="+data);
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.place,
                        }

                    }));
                } //success end
            }); //ajax end
        }, //source end
        minLength: 0, 
}); //autocomplete end
```

Try to send the csrf token in your `ajax request` as data

```
 data: {
          findtable : findtable,
          term : terms,
          _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')  
        },
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! But the error is still in!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this in a plugin called easyAutocomplete and worked miraculously,  
easyAutocomplete({
        url         : function(phrase) {    return "/admin/api?t=myusers";  },
        getValue    : function(element) {    return element.name;  },
    ajaxSettings    : { 
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },