# Laravel "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException" error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

In my Laravel, Vue JS application, I'm getting this type of error after I transferred my application to our server.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException

I saw the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850695/csrf-token-error-on-laravel-symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-httpexce/52511224?noredirect=1#comment91962885_52511224) but there's no answer. I hope this time there will be someone that can provide an answer or solution for this type of error.

**Note:**

1. This error only happens if I tried to access the application from a server using other devices.
2. Error occurs **irregularly**. If it doesn't show on first, sometimes shows-up after 2 or more ajax request.
3. I'm using [vForm](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform) for my ajax request.
4. It works fine on my pc/localhost.
5. It works fine as well when I tried to access my application inside my server. I mean, I tried to use the browser inside our server and it works with no problem.

**PS.**

- I checked my **Request Header** and `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is there.
- In my **Request Payload** `_token` is there as well.

**Below are my codes:**

VueJS Method:

```
UpdateDepartmentInfo(){

            this.departmentToUpdate._token = this.$root.csrf;

            this.requestUpdateDepartmentOnProgress = true;

            this.departmentToUpdate.put('department/'+this.departmentToUpdate.id)
                .then((response) => {              
                    this.requestUpdateDepartmentOnProgress = false;      
                    this.GetDepartmentList();
                    swal(
                        'Department Info. Saved!',
                        'Department information has been successfully updated to database!',
                        'success'
                    );
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.requestUpdateDepartmentOnProgress = false;
                    if (error.response.status == 401) {
                        alert('User session has expired. Please login again.');
                        location.replace("/login");
                    }
                });
        }
```

Laravel Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        // Check if the department object from model if it exists
        try{
            $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return response(['error' => 'The department you want to edit can\'t be found in the database!' ], 400);
        }

        // check if it was just the status was sent 
        if($request['newStat'] != null){
            $department->status  = $request['newStat'];
        }else{

            $this->validate($request,[
                'name'      => 'required|string|max:191',
                'code'      => 'required|string|max:10',
            ]);

            $department->name           = $request['name'];
            $department->code           = $request['code'];
            $department->description    = $request['description'];
            $department->status         = $request['status'];       
        }

        $department->save();
        return ['message' => 'ok'];


    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: what is in your `.env` APP_URL

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta - `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: @cbaconnier - I cannot find error or the stracktrace in my `laravel.log` but in the response here it is: (wait i don't know how to attached screenshot)

Comment: @cbaconnier - I can't even pasted the trace response here cause it's too long.

Comment: You code seems fine, unless status, description or newStat are not the attended type. It will be very difficult to help you without the stacktrace or the content+headers of your working/broke requests.

Comment: Is it possible that the `PHPSESSID` is causing the error? when I access the application in my localhost and browser inside server they both don't have this `PHPSESSID` only this `XSRF-TOKEN` and `myappname_session` and it works fine. How to remove this `PHPSESSID`?

Comment: @cbaconnier - i put [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q6n2ZzZfqqrTDyIcjWelIBFYWkzPBKvvB90wJIQMvU0/edit?usp=sharing) the stacktrace.

Comment: What's the HTTP code in the response? 419 ? I suspect a csrf token expiration

Comment: @cbaconnier - Yes it's 419. so do you know the reason why it expires?

Comment: By default it expire after 120 minutes for [security reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/140165). Since you're mostly using VueJS, I guess you aren't reloading the page while using the form. Here's a trick to update  your csrf token: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449434/handling-expired-token-in-laravel

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue here, tried the solutions but still not working, here is a link : https://buynow.liqstage.co.za/

Answer (score 0):

in your .env file make changes like this

```
APP_URL=http://your_server_url
```

or you have to put thin in your `index.php` file

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost");
```

Comment: Tried both suggestions but still getting the error. I can't really seems to understand why I'm getting the error cause if i use the server browser it works fine. I just get the error if i tried to access it publicly. Isn't it because of the delay?

Comment: updated the answer please check and let me know if not works

Comment: already put `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost");` at the very top inside `public\index.php` but unfortunately the error is still there. :(

Answer (score 0):

check in the resources/js/components folder in you component if you have 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/fetchusers`

change it to

```
 fetch('fetchusers',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                X_CSRF_TOKEN:('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
                'Accept':'application/json'
            }
        })
```

it might help.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the csrf_token usually, you can check this documentation hope it will solve yours too.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

To do:
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

````
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});```
````

Answer (score -1):

check your `storage/log/laravel.log` file is there. Also they have permission to write/read

this can be fixed quite easily by running:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs
```

Comment: Do not advice to `chmod 777`! That can't be a solution, ever!

Comment: They are not using linux server here. They are using the windows server OS. By the way i checked my `laravel.log` and the permission is set to read/write.